# Connecting to website in Node with TCP sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I was just curious how I would go about connecting to websites (relatively generically) in Node.js. My main question being centered around the following:

```
var s = require('net').Socket();

//this spits out data
s.connect(80, 'google.com');
s.write("GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1\n\n");

//this does not
s.connect(80, 'reddit.com');
s.write('GET https://www.reddit.com/ HTTP/1.1\n\n');
```

why is this? How would I go about building this functionality from a raw request. It yields a bad request. Maybe I am confused on how to appropriately format my GET request. But the raw requests seem identical...

Answer (score 0):

The Https part is more involved at the IP layer.  Take out the https and make it http if you want to try this raw direct method.     How 443 works is not as simple.  It easy with many libraries that are out there however.  If you use 443 instead of port 80 many libraries do the work for you.